# Not able to reach azure url

Tags: networking, security, unix, azure, java

I am trying to reach azure url through my Unix server but not able to reach it. It is sending connection time out and not able to find server from server list every time.

Plus I have tried to ping google and it is working fine I don't see any any security firewall against it.

What could be the reason barring the access

Comment: What s the URL you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your server has the Internet connection since the google is reachable.

To troubleshoot this kind of issue, please follow the steps below:

- Make sure that the FQDN of the resource is able to be resolved into
  correct IP address. nslookup is a good tool to verify that.
- Make sure that there is a routable path between your server and the
  resource. Ping/TraceRoute should help if ICMP is not disabled.
- Make sure that the ports used by the service are not blocked by any
  firewalls. There are a lot of port detection tools, choose anyone you prefer.

If all these tests are passed, then you may need to perform a network capture on your server to check if the TCP connections have been established properly.

If the TCP connection is fine, then the issue may occur at application layer. Please provide more detailed information about this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 (and/or 443) are not open to your Azure VM by default.  Azure has its own firewall that needs to be managed in addition to any OS firewalls that might be in place.

Fix this by going to "All Resources", and find the "Network Security Group" that is tied to your VM.  Add an inbound security rule for the ports you need open, such as HTTP (TCP/80) or HTTPS (TCP/443).